# Why code color will change in Visual Studio Code Code when setting python method return type?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes

I have a mystic problem with settings in VS code when programming with Python. Coloring is working perfectly until I add the method return value type (see the picture). read_validations does have return value type in upper picture and next method (read_location) def keyword (also "return" and "@") will change to white color. When return type is not defined, the def keyword color will be blue.

Can anyone help with this problem?

[two methods. read_validations does have return type in upper picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15sCk.png)

Comment: Did you import the library List with : *from typing import List*

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to import List :

```
 from typing import List
```

I think what is missing here are the brackets:

```
def read_validations(self) -> List[] :
```

And even better, you should specify what type of object you list will contain :

```
def validate(self, item:dict, attrs:dict)-> List[str]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. And the coloring in the VSCode is related to the theme. can you try to switch to a different theme?

I am using the `SynthWave '84`, you can have a try.

And you can custom the coloring policy manually in the settings.json, for example:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "functions": "#0077ff",
    "comments": "#0004ff",
    "keywords": "#c8ff00",
    "numbers": "#ff00ea",
    "strings": "#FF0000",
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "source.python meta.function-call.python",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#72f1b8",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        }
      }
    ],
    "types": "#00e1ff",
    "variables": "#ff8800"
  },
```

Comment: I tried to change theme but it did not help at all, but the main reason is extension Python  for VSCode. When I disabled the extension, everything is working fine. I do not know what is the reason the extension will cause the problem ... any way now it is working.

Comment: @Risahdus As you disabled the Python extension, how can you run the python files?